# How to display data across, by row, in pie chart in plotly/streamlit?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, streamlit

I have pandas df that looks like this that I want to display as a dashboard:

```
fname    col1      col2     col3    sum 
A         2         3         3      10
B         1         2         3      12
C         6         6         3      13
```

If a `fname` is selected by row, I want to display the pie slices as the column values by row.

What is the best way to display the data by `fname` grouped across by row in a pie chart?

I am not sure what to display when all the column values for `fname` are selected.

I tried creating a sunburst chart like so, but the chart is extremely convoluted:

```
 px.sunburst(df, values='sum', path=[
        'col3',
        'col2',
        'col1',
        'fname'],
        title='pie')
```

Comment: Do you want to create a pie chart or a sunburst or both? Or you want suggestions what chart to build to possibly best represent your data frame.

Comment: @ferdy, thanks for the response. I would like the best chart to build for the data, and if possible the circle chart.

Comment: Can you tell us what is A, B and C. col1, col2, col3 represents?

Comment: @ferdy, they represent just counts. For example, A could be how many outreaches did you do ? 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic example.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

data = {
    'ctry': ['USA', 'PHI', 'CHN'],
    'gold': [12, 1, 20,],
    'silver': [4,4, 12],
    'bronze': [8, 2, 30],
    'sum': [24, 7, 62]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
st.dataframe(df)

cols = st.columns([1, 1])

with cols[0]:
    medal_type = st.selectbox('Medal Type', ['gold', 'silver', 'bronze'])
    
    fig = px.pie(df, values=medal_type, names='ctry',
                 title=f'number of {medal_type} medals',
                 height=300, width=200)
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=30, b=0),)
    st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)

with cols[1]:
    st.text_input('sunburst', label_visibility='hidden', disabled=True)
    fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['ctry', 'gold', 'silver', 'bronze'],
                      values='sum', height=300, width=200)
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=30, b=0),)
    st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: you are amazing @ferdy! thank you so much you just solved the issue for me!